# Php Как инициировать скачивание внешнего файла?

Tags: php

Сам использую этот скрипт:

Но если загоняю в него url к примеру http://site.com/archive.zip
то ничего не происходит, скачивает только локальные файлы, но не внешние

```
function file_force_download($file) {
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    // сбрасываем буфер вывода PHP, чтобы избежать переполнения памяти выделенной под скрипт
    // если этого не сделать файл будет читаться в память полностью!
    if (ob_get_level()) {
      ob_end_clean();
    }
    // заставляем браузер показать окно сохранения файла
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    // читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
    readfile($file);
    exit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Погоди ка - file_exists работает только с локальными файлами не?
[Читай доку](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-exists.php)

Смотри ты когда пытаешся получить файл **if (file_exists($file))** будет всегда **false** ( если файл удаленный ) 
И ты не чего не увидишь, убери это и запроси удаленный файл и ты увидишь что все работает, да кстати тигать так файлы плохая идея там еще могут быть всякие редиректы и тому подобное но это уже выходит за рамки вопроса.

```
function file_force_download($file) {
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
```

}

Вот так файл отдается, вообщем тебе надо доработать проверки с поправкой на то что файлы на удаленном сервере :)